# Don't update modify time post on Quick Edit

Tags: customization

How can I disable updating modify post time when something is changed in Quick Edit mode?

I found this snippet but I don't know how to implement that to reflect in Quick Edit mode?

```
function stop_modified_date_update( $new, $old ) {
$new['post_modified'] = $old['post_modified'];
$new['post_modified_gmt'] = $old['post_modified_gmt'];
return $new;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'stop_modified_date_update', 10, 2 );
remove_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'stop_modified_date_update', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: what's the problem you're trying to solve by doing this? Using quick edit modifies the post so it's still accurate. Note that you're adding a filter then immediatley removing it before it can ever be used

Comment: Hi Tom, Yes, quick edit updated post, and this function uses old value form post_modified meta field and override new value with it, so modified field actually never change. It works as expected, but it works both in Post Editor and Quick Editor. I want to use it only when post is updated in Quick Edit mode.